# Working Around position:static in setting z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to get an element rendered later in the HTML to display in front of an element with explicit z-index - see below:

Here's my situation:

(jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hephistocles/78Wpc/)

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    ...
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="navigation">
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
#slider {
    z-index:20;
}
#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
}
```

I've put my navigation in the footer because I want my slider and content to load before the navigation stuff does. I then use CSS to pull the navigation up so it's displayed above the slider.

I want the navigation to be rendered above the slider (z-index wise) so the dropdowns are clickable. I also want the slider to be clickable (so z-index:-1 isn't an option). I need #footer to have position:static so I can't set a z-index there.

I think the answer lies in restructuring my HTML to some extent, but I do want to preserve the basic organisation of it if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited to clarify that the slider had a z-index, and to add a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both elements are still in the same stack context, so just add `z-index: 21` (something higher than `#slider`) to the `#navigation` and it pushes the `#navigation` higher. [See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/78Wpc/1/)

Assuming you don't set a `z-index` on `#header` or `#footer` (which you said you wanted to remain static anyway), then there will *not* be a change of the stack context just because it is nested inside another `div`. Once `z-index` is set, *then* the stack context changes for child elements.

Comment: Well that was silly; I could have sworn I tried that and it hadn't worked. Thanks anyway.